# My test cases in spring boot app are reading from main application.yaml file instead of application-test.yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

I am using profiles("test") in my test class but then also while running spring boot test cases it uses my yaml from src/main/resources instead from test/resources/application-test.yaml.

I used @ActiveProfiles annotation and I expect to pick the data from test folder yaml file.

[image]

Comment: did you forget to write `src/` in front of `test/resources/` or is it the correct folder. If so, you need to move it. And, in any cases, you should have application.yml in the test folder

Comment: Yes the correct folder structure is src/test/resources/application.yaml but my test cases are not using the values from this application.yaml, they are using from src/main/resources/application.yaml.

Comment: If possible Can you please share project code or code snippet

Comment: Project structure would help to figure this out

Comment: Added the folder structure image in question description.

Comment: Move everything from `src/test/main/` folder to `src/test/` (1 level up), and delete `src/test/main` (so that `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` remain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src/test/`**`main/`**`resources` is "weird"!
To fix the issue move `resources` (and `java`) folder to `src/test/`, to conform with "maven project structure".